# Vector recycling concept in R

Tags: r

I am trying to understand the working of vector recycling in R. I have 2 vectors

```
c(2,4,6)
```

and

```
c(1,2)
```

And I want to use the `rep()` to produce an output as follows:

```
[1]  2  4  6  4  8 12
```

based on what I understand from `?rep()` is that there are `times` and `each` parameters which do the operations which I tried.

```
> rep(c(2,4,6), times=2)
[1] 2 4 6 2 4 6
```

But I also see the first vector is multiplied by the first element of the second vector and then to the second element of the second vector. Not sure how to proceed with it.

Comment: This works, though there may be a simpler way to do it: `as.vector(mapply(function(x) x * c(2, 4, 6), 1:2))`  Note that proper recycling requires that the recycled elements be integer multiples.  E.g. `rnorm(6, 1:6, 1:2)`  Would generate 6 normal realizations with means 1:6 and sd 1:2 repeated 3x.

Comment: You can do `c(1,2) %x% c(2,4,6)`, see `?kronecker`

Comment: Matrix multiplication `%*%` may also give you desired results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
rep(c(2,4,6), 2) * rep(c(1,2), each=3)
#[1]  2  4  6  4  8 12
```

or with auto recycling:

```
c(2,4,6) * rep(c(1,2), each=3)
#[1]  2  4  6  4  8 12
```

Alternative `outer` could be used:

```
c(outer(c(2,4,6), c(1,2)))
#[1]  2  4  6  4  8 12
```

Also `crossprod` could be used:

```
c(crossprod(t(c(2,4,6)), c(1,2)))
#[1]  2  4  6  4  8 12
```

Or `%*%`:

```
c(c(2,4,6) %*% t(c(1,2)))
#[1]  2  4  6  4  8 12
```